# What counts as a MapKitJs call?

Tags: mapkit, mapkit-js

MapKitJS offers 250,000 free map calls per day at the current time (June 2021). This raises the question for me, what is counted as a call?

Is the call counted when the `mapkit.init(...)` method is called or when a new map instance is created?

For example, if I create two maps on my website with the methods:

```
const map1 = new mapkit.Map(container1, { ... } );
const map2 = new mapkit.Map(container2, { ... } );
```

but only call `mapkit.init(...)` once, does that still count as only one call or two?